# HOW Detect Telegram Protocol from it's TCP headers?

Tags: tcp, header, protocols, detection, telegram

I have some clients connected to my server. I want to know how much they use telegram (from it's desktop and mobile application).
can anyone explain me how can I detect this protocol from header of the packets?
I read this from Telegram official site:
There is an abridged version of the same protocol: if the client sends 0xef as the first byte (important: only prior to the very first data packet), then packet length is encoded by a single byte (0x01..0x7e = data length divided by 4; or 0x7f followed by 3 length bytes (little endian) divided by 4) followed by the data themselves (sequence number and CRC32 not added). 
but I didn't understand when abridged version is used?

Comment: This has nothing to do with TCP headers. You are talking about the content of the payload for the TCP packets here (i.e. application data) and not about the TCP header which cares about port number, TCP flags, sequence numbers etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telegram uses [MTProto](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto) to communicate. Check [this page](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description) for more details of the packets. Every packet is encrypted so you can't see inside.

By the way, if I was in your shoes, I would filter packets by their source and destination IP address. Telegram has dedicated servers with fixed IPs. All you have to do is to find all Telegram IP addresses. If any packet is coming from or going to these IPs, it's someone using Telegram.